Wordpress custom post types submenus
I am trying to make a WordPress plugin with custom post types. For creating the posts I have need to use a form, and I want to either replace or remove the default post creation submenu. Anyone know how to do that?
Here's the code i have right now:
function create_sensor_post_type() {
    global $wp_query;
    if (!isset($wp_query)) {
        return;
    }
    // Register the 'sensors' custom post type
    register_post_type('sensors',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Sensors'),
                'singular_name' => __('Sensor')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'sensor'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus',
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor') // Adjusted 'supports' to include 'title' and 'editor'
        )
    );



    function add_sensor_menu_page() {
        add_submenu_page(
            'edit.php?post_type=sensors', // Parent menu slug
            'Add New Sensor', // Page title
            'Add New', // Menu title
            'manage_options', // Capability
            'add-new-sensor', // Menu slug
            'custom_sensor_form_page' // Callback function
        );
    }

function custom_sensor_form_page() {...}

Tried this code:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#menu-posts-sensors .wp-submenu li:nth-child(3)').hide();
});

It hid the menu only when I was in a specific submenu, otherwise it kept showing
